# How to restrict unauthenticated RPC clients using powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, security, group-policy

The manual way to solve this is: Local Group Policy Editor > Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Remote Procedure Call > Change “Restrict Unauthenticated RPC clients” to configured and authenticated.

But I want to be able to script this into powershell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update the corresponding registry setting. Check out the [admx.help page](https://admx.help/?Category=Windows_10_2016&Policy=Microsoft.Policies.RemoteProcedureCalls::RpcRestrictRemoteClients) on that policy for information about which values to use:

```
Set-ItemProperty "HKLM:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Rpc" -Name RestrictRemoteClients -Value 2
```

If the reg key doesn't already exist, then you may have to create it with `New-Item`
and/or `New-ItemProperty` instead.

Comment: Ok thanks I really appreciate it